# Adding source file to .bash_profile

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks, bash

Just installed rvm on my Mac, and it gave me this message:

- WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
  to do that add the following line to '/Users/pdenlinger/.bash_profile':

  source ~/.profile

So opened up .bash_profile and added it like this:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/Scala/bin/:${PATH}"
export PATH
CLASSPATH="$HOME/AtomicScala/code:${CLASSPATH}"
export CLASSPATH
export EDITOR='subl -w'
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.profile`

Have no experience editing the path variables, so would like to know if I did this correctly? If not, what is the right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you did it good, run rvm update to see if the warning is gone:

```
rvm get head
```

btw. you could improve your config like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/Scala/bin/:${PATH}"
export CLASSPATH="$HOME/AtomicScala/code:${CLASSPATH}"
export EDITOR='subl -w'
source ~/.profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```